# Powershell - When watching folder for new file created - if statement inside "Register-ObjectEvent" is not firing

Tags: powershell

**Goal:** File watcher watches the staging folder for new files. If the new file name contains "JDE_Reimb" then move the file into another folder "`$reimb_jde_path`" ,also renaming the new file.

**Issue:** The `If` statement is not firing me at all. Up to creating the `$fullpath` works, but my `If` statement is not executing. Any ideas why? Also I need to watch this folder for 2 other file which contain specific string in the file name. What is the best way to accomplish this in one script?

```
$reimbFile = "JDE_Reimb"
$reimb_jde_path = "\\rootfolder\reimbfolder"
$staging_folder_path = "\\rootfolder\stagingfolder\"                                    #"
$filter = "*.txt"

$watcherCRExport_Staging = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $staging_folder_path, $filter -Property @{
  IncludeSubdirectories = $false
}

Register-ObjectEvent $watcherCRExport_Staging Created -SourceIdentifier foldertest -Action {

  $text = $eventArgs.Name
  Write-Host $text# Write-Host $eventArgs.ChangeType
  $fullpath = Join-Path -Path $staging_file_path -ChildPath $text# Write-Host "Full path is: $fullpath"

  If($text.Contains($reimbFile)) {
    $newtext = $text.Substring(0, $text.IndexOf("_") + 1 + $text.Substring($text.IndexOf("_") + 1).IndexOf("_"))# Write-Host "Created: $($newtext)"
    $newfilename = $newtext + ".txt"
    $nextpath = Join-Path -Path $reimb_jde_path -ChildPath $newtext
    Copy-Item-Path $fullpath -Destination $nextpath
    Write-Host "---------------------------------"
    Write-Host $newfilename
    Write-Host $fullpath
    Write-Host $nextpath
    Write-Host "Reimbursement Done copying"
    Write-Host "---------------------------------"
  }
  Else {
    Write-Host "No Match!"
  }

}
```

Comment: So if you `Write-Host` the value of `$text` and `($text | Get-Member)` before the `if` statement in a case where you expect the `if` to be entered, what do you get? Also note that you could try to set up your filter as `$filter = '*JDE_Reimb*.txt'` to begin with, then you'd only get events for the files of interest.

Comment: @mklement0  I have it working up to but not including Copy-Item command. I get a "The process cannot access the file" error. Any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: Well, it sounds like the target file is in use. You need to ensure that it isn't in use first, only then you can copy over it.

Comment: @mklement0 upon further inspection. This script works perfectly for when I do it in my local C drive in test folders. But because I am doing this in network shared folder, there is some kind permission or something causing the issue I think. When it comes to network drives copy-item, should I handle the code differently?

Comment: Your current problem doesn't match your question anymore. Given that no answers were given yet, I suggest you rewrite it to focus just on your current problem, providing as much information as you can, including full error messages.

Comment: @mklement0 your solution works for my original question. Sorry I steered off course there, but ill leave this as per original question. Your answer helped.

Comment: I see, but could you please write up what, specifically, helped _as an answer_, so that a potential solution to future readers with similar problems is more obvious.